# Express.js: Cookie being saved late

Tags: node.js, cookies, express

I think this is because of the asynchronous nature of Node.js in general.

I am changing a cookie's value, then rendering a new page. However upon rendering the new page, the page shows the just-overwritten contents of the cookie. It's as if the cookie is being saved a step late.

```
res.cookie('loginid',req.body.name,{maxAge:60000});
res.render('page1');
```

In page1, I have:

```
<% if(req.cookies.loginid){ %>
cookie remembered. Hi, <%= req.cookies.loginid %>! <% } %>
```

Example: Cookie currently has loginid="id1". I set it to id2, then render page1. Then I am sent to page1 and of course, it shows id1. If I repeat the procedure by replacing id2 with id3, page1's contents will show id2, and so on.

I tried doing a callback on the res.cookie(...) function, but nothing was called inside it. It looked like:

```
 res.cookie('loginid',req.body.name,{maxAge:60000}, function(req,res){console.log('test');});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your template (or any other code for that matter) accesses `req.cookies`, it will access the cookies that were sent by the client (so the values that were previously set, in a different request, using `res.cookie()`).

Those cookies are independent of cookies that you are setting using `res.cookie()`, so using that won't update any values in `req.cookies` within the same request (you're merely telling Express, *when this request is done, please include a `Set-Cookie` header in the response with this value*).

Since you're storing `req.body.name` as cookie value, you can just use that in rendering your template:

```
res.render('page1', { loginid : req.body.name });
```

And in your template:

```
<% if (loginid) { %>
cookie remembered. Hi, <%= loginid %>! <% } %>
```

(However, you cannot be sure at the time of rendering that the cookie that you are sending back will actually be accepted by the client, so technically saying *cookie remembered* is premature).